# How do I get access to the SpriteBatch service in my Sprite class using XNA?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, design-patterns, game-component

I have the following `Sprite` class (leaving out everything that doesn't pertain to my question):

```
public class Sprite
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;

    public Sprite(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
    {
        Texture = texture;
        Position = position;

        // what code do I put here?
        _spriteBatch = ???
    }

    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        _spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position, Color.White);
    }
```

In my `Game1.cs` class, I register the SpriteBatch as a service:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    Services.AddService(_spriteBatch);
}
```

Problem is, I don't know what code to put in the `Sprite` constructor to get the `SpriteBatch` object from the service. It doesn't have access to the `Game.Services` object. How would I load the service in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is completely a matter of taste.

You could pass your `Game` class instance into the constructor of your `Sprite` and access its public `Services` property. This is what `DrawableGameComponent` and `GraphicsDeviceManager` do.

You could pass `Game.Services` as an `IServiceProvider` into the constructor of your `Sprite` class. This is what the `ContentManager` class does. This has the advantage of not depending on an actual instance of `Game` (which you might not have if, say, you end up making a form-based level editor).

You could just pass an instance of `SpriteBatch` in the constructor of your `Sprite` class, but you can then only create `Sprite` objects after you create your `SpriteBatch`, which you can only do during and after `LoadContent`.

You could get especially lazy and create a globally accessible `Game` or `IServiceProvider` or `SpriteBatch` object and just use that (make it a static property on your game class). Advantage: quick and easy; Disadvantage: ugly!

You could pass a `SpriteBatch` instance into your `Sprite.Draw` method. This is pretty easy to do, and **is the method I use** for my gameplay classes - things that might have a `Draw` and an `Update` function (eg: a Player, or an Enemy, etc). One advantage is that it makes it both locally explicit and easy to modify the shared resources that the `Draw` function depends on.

But if your `Sprite` class is simply visual data for `SpriteBatch` (texture, position, etc), which is managed externally (having public setters for these properties, in your example, indicates that it might be), then I would recommend creating an **extension method** for `SpriteBatch` that does the drawing. This allows you to maintain the "feel" of the `SpriteBatch` object. Your extension method might look like:

```
public static void Draw(this SpriteBatch sb, Sprite sprite)
{
    sb.Draw(sprite.Texture, sprite.Position, Color.White);
}
```

Allowing you to draw it with: `sb.Draw(sprite);`. This method is preferable if you are not doing `SpriteBatch.Begin` and `.End` calls in your `Draw` method - as this allows it to work the same as `SpriteBatch`.

Those last two methods are the ones that I use and recommend myself.

**But** you have done something that strikes me as *pretty unusual* by making your `Sprite.Draw` method `virtual` - indicating that you will be inheriting from `Sprite` and using it virtually. But combining this with public setters, and not calling `Begin` and `End`, makes for a pretty *confused* design.

If this is *really* the design you intend to use, then passing an `IServiceProvider` to the `Sprite` constructor is probably the best method to use as it allows for better encapsulation. (Just fix up those other things, which don't ;)

Comment: And +1 to you also; but, what is *"confused"* about not calling `Begin()`/`End()`?  It makes sense to me - he wants the drawing code in the sprite class, but doesn't want every sprite to be in its own batch.  He presumably has a sprite-manager `DrawableGameComponent` which loops over all the sprites and calls `Draw()` on them individually, within a single sprite-batch.  This is exactly how I'd do it.

Comment: @BlueRaja: For performance, it is best to batch together sprites (that have the same texture), and often performance will take precedence over a "nice" design. It is nice to say "share this `SpriteBatch` object, but leave it in its base (not-in-batch) state when you're done". It's also reasonably nice to say "my draw function takes a `SpriteBatch` parameter that is already in-batch with the correct settings". It is *not* so nice to say "share this `SpriteBatch` object, and trust us that we'll put it in the right state before calling your `Draw` method".

Comment: In particular, the latter design can encourage ugly hacks like: `{ End; Begin(my settings); DrawMyStuff; End; Begin(try to reset); }` - and that is very much *un-nice*. And, again, architecture is a matter of taste - these are not hard-and-fast rules. You might recall that I don't like `DrawableGameComponent`, and one reason is that it can force you to use this less-nice architecture (which *works*, it's just not *nice*).

Comment: I still don't get it.  If any classes need different `SpriteBatch` settings, they can create their own instance - there's nothing wrong with multiple overlapping sprite-batches.  Otherwise, not forcing every class to call Begin/End is more convenient and *(as I understand it; I've never profiled it)* more performant.  The same argument applies whether or not he's actually using `GameComponent`s.

Comment: You are telling me that it will *work* and that it might be more performant (it is, if consecutive sprites share the same texture). I don't disagree with you! You suggest that it is more "convenient" - I think you mean "convenient to write". Whereas an indicator of a good architecture is that it is *convenient to **read***. All of these factors need to be balanced. All I am saying is that, on the "nice architecture" factor *alone*, having a member who's state is shared and changed externally is an ugly design (*especially* in a class designed to be inherited from).

Comment: Of course they shouldn't be changing settings on the sprite-batch; if they need to use anything other than the default, they should just create another sprite-batch.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of possibilities :

- Pass it in the constructor
- Pass the Services object in the constructor
- Pass it to your Sprite.Draw function

The right solution depends on your overall architecture.

Comment: +1; see [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14217/several-classes-need-to-access-the-same-data-where-should-the-data-be-declared/14232#14232) for more information.

Comment: @BlueRaja Great answer.