# When one should use events in Unity and how they impact performance?

Tags: unity, performance, events

let's say that inside an ***OnGUI()*** script we want to call a method from another script to handle a particular situation. From a prestational point of view, what's the difference between these 3 approaches?

1.

```
    public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour{

        ...

        void OnGUI(){
            if(something)
                 otherClass.heavyWorkMethod();
            ...
        }
    }
```

2.

```
public class SomeClassCoroutine : MonoBehavior{   

    ...

    void OnGUI(){
        if(something)
            StartCoroutine("someClassCoroutine");
        ...
    }

    IEnumerator someClassCoroutine(){
        otherClass.heavyWorkMethod();
        ...
    }
}
```

3.

```
public class SomeClassEvent : MonoBehavior{
    public delegate void SomeAction();
    public static event SomeAction OnEvent;
    ...

    void OnGUI(){
        if(something)
            OnEvent();
    }
}
```

Where in the third case, the ***heavyWorkMethod*** in ***OtherClass*** gets called when the event ***OnEvent*** is fired.

Thanks for your time. Looking forward to read your answers.

Answer (score 2):

(1) is just a normal method call.

(2) is a [Unity Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html).  You should only use it when you need the special abilities that coroutines grant you *(basically, when you need the execution of a single method to last multiple frames)*

(3) is normal [C# event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  You can read about events in any book or tutorial on C#, but without getting into too much detail:  they're used to signal that some event has occurred.  This allows the users of your class to decide which events they care to handle, and which they don't.  It's also a way to call methods higher up in the call-hierarchy.

*(Note that it's very unusual to have a static-event.  In every case I can think of that you'd use a static event, using a [service](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14217/14232#14232) would be better design)*.

---

There is a fourth option you missed:  [Unity Messages](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html).  A message is similar to an event that all other `Component`s attached to that `GameObject` are automatically subscribed to.  This allows your component to publish an event without other components having to explicitly subscribe to it.  Functions like `Start()`, `Awake()`, `OnGui` etc. are all messages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From a prestational point of view, though, when one has to deal with blocking operations is there a sensible difference between _coroutines_ and _events_? What I mean, looking at the example above, is that: are both effective ways of dealing with blocking operations?